# Calling custom methods in a React Page Component from the Columns definition Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-table

My Question revolves around 3 files,

1. `BasicTable.jsx` - The Table component using React Table.
2. `CategoryCOLUMNS.jsx` - The columns definition for the columns in the Table component
3. `Category.jsx` - the Category component where the function is defined.

The issue is that i am trying to call the `deleteCatData` function defined in the `Category.jsx` file from the `CategoryColumns.jsx` file  on every column.  so that once the delete button is pressed a row is deleted via the function on the `Category.jsx` file and then the table is rendered.

how can i achieve this, or if there is a better way, i'm just tyring to delete the individual rows and update the table because i keep getting errors.

**BasicTable.jsx**

```
import React, { useMemo} from 'react'; 
import { useTable } from 'react-table';
import uuid from 'react-uuid';

import './table.css';

export const BasicTable = (props) => {

    //using the useMemo ensures that the data 
    //isnt created on every render... 
    const tb_columns = useMemo(() =>props.cols, []); 
    const tb_data = useMemo(() => props.data, []); 

    const tbObj = useTable({ columns: tb_columns,  data: tb_data });

    const {
        getTableProps, 
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups, 

        rows,
        prepareRow
    } = tbObj;

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
            {
                headerGroups.map(hg => (
                    <tr {...hg.getHeaderGroupProps()}> 
                    { hg.headers.map((col) => <th {...col.getHeaderProps()}> { col.render('Header') } </th>)}
                          
                    </tr> 
                ))
            }
            
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {
                rows.map(rw => {
                    prepareRow(rw); 
                    return (<tr {...rw.getRowProps()}> { rw.cells.map((cell) => <td {...cell.getCellProps}> { cell.render('Cell') } </td>)} </tr>)
                })
            }
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
 
    </table>
  )
};
```

**CategoryCOLUMNS.jsx**

```
import * as Icon from 'react-bootstrap-icons';

export const CategoryModel = [
    { 
        Header: 'id',                       
        accessor: 'id',                
        disableFilters:true, 

    },
    { 
        Header: 'Title',        
        accessor: 'title',  
        width:1000
    },
    { 
        Header: 'Description',   
        accessor: 'description',     
    },
    
    {
        Header: "Actions",        
        disableFilters:true, 
        Cell: ({ cell, row }) => (<div className='flex space-x-3'>


            <button className='border-solid border-2 px-0.5 py-0.5 ml-1 rounded-md hover:border-neutral-950' 
            onClick={()=> delCatData(row['id'])}> <Icon.X /> Delete Category </button> 

        </div>)
    }
];
```

on the Category's page

**Category.jsx**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'; 
import { CategoryModel } from '../models/CategoryCOLUMNS';
import { TableComp } from '../tables/TableComp';
import * as api from '../../data/apis';

const fetchData = async() => {
    return await api.fetchAllCategorys();   // call api here..
}

const delData = async(data) => {
   return await api.deleteCategoryData(data); //delete data here... 
}

export const Category = () => {
 
 const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState([]);
 const [dataIsReady, setDataIsReady] = useState(false);     
 
  useEffect(()=>{                      // load all categories on start. 
      fetchData().then(res => { 
         setCategoryData(res.data);             
         setDataIsReady(true); 
      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, []);


 // how can i pass this function to the table component in the categoryModel File 
 // the cat

 const deleteCatData = (id) => {
   delData(id).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err)); 
 }

   return (
     <div className='w-2/3 '>
        { dataIsReady && <TableComp data={categoryData}  cols={CategoryCOLUMNS} /> } 
     </div>
   )
}

export default Category;
```